# read_excel in Rshiny not skipping lines despite "skip = 4" being an argument

Tags: r, shiny, readxl

I have a line in my rshiny script calling an upload input:

```
osha <- read_excel(input$file4$datapath, skip = 4, sheet = "Data") %>%
   do.stuff
```

And the lines are not skipping as a memo pops up saying

```
New names:
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...5
* `` -> ...6
Warning: Error in months: object 'for doing do.stuff' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

This exact line has worked in other shiny apps I've built.

when I call the file in another script

```
osha <- read_excel("file.xlsx", skip = 4, sheet = "Data") %>%
   do.stuff
```

do.stuff does the stuff.

What gives?

Comment: The new names refer to column names - do you have unnamed columns in the excel sheet you're trying to import?

Comment: Yes. There's some information not in tabular form at the top of the spreadsheet. That's why I need to cut those out, but they're not being removed.